# ¿Cómo puedo sumar la fila de numeros impares del siguiente triangulo?

Tags: python

Voy apenas iniciando con la programación, pero despúes de intentarlo varias veces no pudé encontrarle una solucion a este problema.

Dado el triángulo a continuación, defina una función que acepte como argumento un número y retorne la suma de los números en la fila que corresponda al argumento.

Ejemplo:

```
sumar(2); == 3 + 5 = 8

sumar(4); == 13 + 15 + 17 + 19 = 64

(1) -->            1

(2) -->         3     5

(3) -->     7     9    11

(4) -->   13    15    17    19

(5) -->21    23    25    27    29

(6) -->........

(7) -->........
```

Si fueran solamente estos valores supongo que seria algo simple, podria aplicar condicionales y obtener los resultados.

Pero se pide suponer que llegue a ser un triangulo o piramide (como gusten verlo) INFINITO. 
Tal que podria pedir el argumento (100) y deberia darme la suma de los impares de dicha fila.

Busco un poco de ayuda o quizas alguna sugerencia sobre que camino seguir y creo que no vale la pena subir los intentos de mi código porque aún no tengo idea de como hacer dicho triangulo.

Psdt: quiero resaltar que apenas voy por el comienzo, pediria alguna solucion sin tantos tecnicismos de ser posible jajaj

Y cualquier propuesta de un punto de vista diferente es bienvenida. Saludos!

Comment: Coloca el codigo que intentasta, sera mas facil ayudar.

Comment: No te preocupes por lo malo o bueno que sea tu código, para eso está la comunidad. Para aprender a programar mejor y para tratar de entender tu manera de pensar el problema. Saludos.

Pd. También depende de qué sea ese "triángulo", podría ser una matriz bidimensional, un dataset o qué se yo. Necesitas especificar mejor el problema para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: uhmm no, ese es el problema no sé como deberia implementar el triangulo.

Comment: o como hacerlo en todo caso

Comment: una función que acepte como argumento un número y retorne la suma de los números en la fila que corresponda al argumento.

Comment: Ejemplo: sumar(2); == 3 + 5 = 8

Comment: sumar(4); == 13 + 15 + 17 + 19 = 64

Comment: El problema tiene una solución muy simple si se usa una aproximación matemática, 1, 3, 7, 13, 21, ... Es una secuencia conocida con una fórmula muy sencilla que solo depende de n, tiene que ver con los números figurados y ya no digo más... XD.  Encuentra la fórmula para esa secuencia y lo tienes hecho... Si obtienes el primer item de la fila el resto son los `n` siguiente impares.

Comment: uhmm vale, ya me diste en que pensar

Comment: GRACIAS... todo consejo se aprecia :)

Answer (score 0):

se puede dar solución al problema si conocemos con que número inicia la fila(ya que la fila n tiene n números), entonces solo tendríamos que iterar por cada fila y asi saber en que número inicia la siguiente fila.

```py
def sumar_fila(n):
    fila = 1 # inica la fila actual, y cuantes elementos hay
    numero_inicio = 1 # el numero de inicio
    ans = 0 # suma en la fila n
    while fila <= n:
        for i in range(fila):
            if n == fila:
                ans += numero_inicio # aqui sumamos la fila
            numero_inicio += 2
        fila += 1
    return ans
```

para más detalle puedes revisar [¿Cómo sumar los números impares en un triángulo con Python?](https://note-code.blogspot.com/2020/05/suma-de-numeros-impares-en-un-triangulo-con-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

Como ya comentaba, existe una forma muy simple y eficiente de realizar el cálculo, basado en que el primer item de cada fila es parte de una secuencia muy conocida y muy fácil de calcular:

- [Central polygonal numbers](http://oeis.org/A002061)

La fórmula es tan simple como:

```
primero = n ** 2 - n + 1
```

dónde `n` es el número de la fila. El resto es trivial:

```
def suma(n):
    primero = n ** 2 - n + 1
    return sum(range(primero, primero + (n * 2), 2))
```

> ```
> >>> suma(3)
> 27
> >>> suma(5)
> 125
> >>> suma(154855225)
> 3713450085147835489515625
> ```

Pero vamos más allá, ¿nadie se percata que la secuencia de sumas tiene algo especial?

> 1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729...

¡son los cubos de `n`!

Por lo que, espero no chafar el magnífico ejercicio de ciclos con Python que alguien diseñó, simplemente:

```
def suma(n):
    return  n ** 3
```